# GoJS bendpoints to shifting points

Tags: gojs

I've got a fairy easy diagram and I'm trying to achieve that the connection lines will have 'bendpoints' or 'shiftpoints', but the diagram ignores my binding ('points'). Am I overseeing something?

The link-connection JSON:

```
[{"id":"Id-4db7b23b","from":"Id-fd544004","to":"Id-a94b6967","label":"","strokewidth":1,"font":"8px Arial","fontcolor":"rgb(0,0,0)","fillcolor":"rgb(238,238,238)","style":"solid","arrowhead":"empty","bendpoints":[["335","363"],["550","234"]]}]
```

where bendpoints are X/Y values.

Source diagram: http://jsfiddle.net/rb7nyxfd/42/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems: if you are using **Model.fromJson**, the link data property needs to be named "points", and the format needs to be an Array of numbers, not an Array of Arrays of strings. So...

Change the Link's binding to be: `new go.Binding("points", "points")`.

Change the link data to be: `"points":[335,363,550,234]`.

Comment: This will only change the direction of the connection lines, not adding extra points. See: http://i.imgur.com/0HeH4aY.png

Comment: **Link.points** always holds the whole route. If you make the Binding a TwoWay Binding, the model will always have a whole list of points, including any points that the user may have inserted.

Comment: But then again, it will still only change the direction of the connection lines, not the shiftpoints it self. See: http://jsfiddle.net/rb7nyxfd/43/.

Comment: If you change the Binding to be: `new go.Binding("points", "points").makeTwoWay()` and if you set `{ reshapable: true, resegmentable: true }` on the Link, then users will be able to add and shift and remove intermediate points along the link route of a selected Link, and the `data.points` property will be updated automatically. Then when you call **Model.toJson** the **List** of **Point**s will be written out as an Array of numbers.

Comment: Thank you. I've got it to work. Is there an function to recalculate the points so the beginning & ending point will be the closest to each other, and not the topleft? See http://jsfiddle.net/rb7nyxfd/44/ for a demo.